# Retrieve only the pod count without listing in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

In an environment with 100 pods each with it's own label 'env=<>'. When I use the command "kubectl get pods --selector env=dev' it gives me 36 pods by listing them. However, I am interested in only the count i.e., 36 and do not want the pods to be listed. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: While the Kubernetes API does not provide a server-side count, you can count resources trivially using the Prometheus metrics exposed by Kubernetes. Example query: `count(kube_pod_info)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rid of the header if you use

```
kubectl get pods --selector env=dev --no-headers | wc -l
```

Comment: So then safe to assume that kubernetes on it's own doesn't have any method to accomplish what I want to. something like a 'count' implementation would have been awesome. Thanks for the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wc -l` to count the line of your output.

```
kubectl get pods --selector env=dev | wc -l
```

Keep in mind that the first line is the header so the number of pods will be that output -1